# Selecting non 1. values in iteration of a data-set while calculating coefficient correlation?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm iterating through the result set of the calculation of correlation values.

The output of this loop:

```
for x in range(DT.shape[1]):
    print np.corrcoef(DT[:, x], YDT, rowvar=False)
```

Is the following:

```
[[ 1.          ,0.58889117],
 [ 0.58889117  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.69343965],
 [ 0.69343965  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.52252876],
 [ 0.52252876  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.65612867],
 [ 0.65612867  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.67349517],
 [ 0.67349517  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.5557239],
 [ 0.5557239   ,1.       ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.69473707],
 [ 0.69473707  ,1.        ]]
[[ 1.          ,0.71186044],
 [ 0.71186044  ,1.        ]]
```

How can I select the values that are not *1.* from the first row? Also, how can I not print each row twice....meaning the first row is [1. 0.58888] and the second one is [0.58888 1.]

For each iteration, I want the decimal values, not the 1's values...without duplication.

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add commas to the output please... really hard to copy and paste otherwise.

Comment: Just select one of the off diag ones : `np.corrcoef(DT[:, x], YDT, rowvar=False)[0,1]`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I hope the formatting is now corrected.

Comment: @Divakar I want to select the decimals, not the ones. Can your suggested solution work with that?

Comment: @Codinghierarchy Did you actually try out : `np.corrcoef(DT[:, x], YDT, rowvar=False)[0,1]`? I hope my code comment wasn't invisible the first time around :)

Comment: I can't try it out now, because I don't have my code at hand, I just wanted to clarify what the line of code does. I will provide insight once I do. I'm at work and this is for school work. I appreciate the time you took to comment.

Comment: @Divakar. I just tested your solution and it's exactly what I expected. If you add it to the solution section I will happily mark it as an answer.

Comment: That's really pretty trivial. Consider deleting the question or adding your own answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Divakar above provided the solution.

```
np.corrcoef(DT[:, x], YDT, rowvar=False)[0,1]
```